# Question about strongly connected components and paths

Tags: graph-theory

Show that all vertices visited in a directed path connecting two vertices in the same
strongly connected component of a directed graph are also in this strongly connected component.

Can someone explain to me how this works? An illustration would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible to get from $a$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $a$, and a directed path from $a$ to $b$ passes through $c$, then you can get from $a$ to $c$ (along the path), or from $c$ to $b$ and then back to $a$.